# Unable to type password in input box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am creating a simple login page. When I declared states and tried to use them in input field's value, I am unable to enter or type anything in the input box.

This problem is occurring only with password input box, email input box is working fine.

```js
export default class SignIn extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            email:'',
            password:''
        };
        this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        };
        handleEmailChange(event) {
            this.setState({email: event.target.value});
            console.log(this.state.email)
        }
        handlePasswordChange(event) {
            this.setState({Password: event.target.value});
            console.log(this.state.password)
        }
        handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const fdata = new FormData()
            fdata.append('email',this.state.email)
            fdata.append('password',this.state.password)
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'abc.com/abc',
                data: fdata
            })
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(response)
                response.json()
            })
            .then(function(responseJson){
                console.log(responseJson)
            })
            .catch(function(){
                alert("Failed")
            })
        }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="container mt-5">
                <form action="/action_page.php">
                    <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
                    <input  type="email"
                            value={this.state.email}
                            onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
                            className="form-control" 
                            id="email"
                            placeholder="Enter email" 
                            name="email" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="pwd">Password:</label>
                    <input  type="password"
                            value={this.state.password}
                            onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
                            className="form-control" 
                            id="pwd" 
                            placeholder="Enter password" 
                            name="pswd" />
                    </div>
<button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I expect to use password state in input type password, and don't want to use any default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your function:

```
handlePasswordChange(event) {
    this.setState({Password: event.target.value}); 
    // should be 
    this.setState({password: event.target.value}); 
    console.log(this.state.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

change Password to password in setState

your code

```
handlePasswordChange(event) {
                this.setState({Password: event.target.value});
                console.log(this.state.password)
            }
```

new code

```
handlePasswordChange(event) {
                this.setState({password: event.target.value});
                console.log(this.state.password)
            }
```